# Adding data to QTableWidget using PyQt4 in Python

Tags: python, pyqt

I want to add my data to a table using pyqt in python. I found that I should use `setItem()` function to add data to a `QTableWidget` and give it the row and column number and a `QTableWidgetItem`. I did it but when I want to display the table, it's completely empty.
Maybe I made a silly mistake but please help me.
Here is my code:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class Table(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Table, self).__init__(parent)
        layout = QtGui.QGridLayout() 
        self.led = QtGui.QLineEdit("Sample")
        self.table = QtGui.QTableWidget()
        layout.addWidget(self.led, 0, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.table, 1, 0)
        self.table.setItem(1, 0, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(self.led.text()))
        self.setLayout(layout)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    t = Table()
    t.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

What you are looking for are the `setRowCount()` and `setColumnCount()` methods. Call these on the `QTableWidget` to specify the number of rows/columns. E.g.

```
...
self.table = QtGui.QTableWidget()
self.table.setRowCount(5)
self.table.setColumnCount(5)
layout.addWidget(self.led, 0, 0)
layout.addWidget(self.table, 1, 0)
self.table.setItem(1, 0, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(self.led.text()))
...
```

This code will make a 5x5 table and display "Sample" in the second row (with index 1) and first column (with index 0).

Without calling these two methods, `QTableWidget` would not know how large the table is, so setting the item at position (1, 0) would not make sense.

In case you are unaware of it, the [Qt Documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/) is detailed and contains many examples (which can easily be converted to Python). The "Detailed Description" sections are especially helpful. If you want more information about `QTableWidget`, go here: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtablewidget.html#details