# PYQT4 : import csv in gui and generate additional row based on data

Tags: python, csv, pyqt4

I have a csv file in the format:

```
xxx,100,200
yyy,300,3
```

I'd like to simply open this csv file, then generate a table based on data as shown below (summing the last two columns):

```
xxx,300
yyy,303
```

Comment: You will have to use some module to read data from .csv file and than you could use `QTableWidget` http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtablewidget.html with its function(s) `setItem()`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11729472/adding-data-to-qtablewidget-using-pyqt4-in-python

Answer (score -1):

On [Github TreeView](https://github.com/Axel-Erfurt/TreeView)
I have some Examples for Read/Write/Print CSV.

with add/remove Rows/Columns

(Python Qt4 / Qt5 or Mono)

in Qt4 I use:

```
def removeColumn(self):
    model = self.model
    indices = self.tableView.selectionModel().selectedColumns() 
    for index in sorted(indices):
        model.removeColumn(index.column()) 

def addColumn(self):
    count = self.model.columnCount()
    print (count)
    self.model.setColumnCount(count + 1)
    self.model.setData(self.model.index(0, count), "new column", 0)
    self.tableView.resizeColumnsToContents()
```

Comment: To improve your post you could paste the most relevant code.

Comment: Try to put code and not a link, as the latter could fall and your answer would no longer be useful.